# Unable to update the argument in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I have a FragmentTabHost and I am adding Tabs to it to show search result:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("AllResults").setIndicator("All Results"),SearchListFragment.class, new Bundle(bundle));
```

When ever user searchs for new string, I need to refresh the Tab. To do so I am removing and adding Tabs again

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("SearchString", searchString);
    mTabHost.clearAllTabs();

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("AllResults").setIndicator("All Results"),SearchListFragment.class, new Bundle(bundle));
```

with updated bundle. But on onCreateView, when I call getArguments I still get old data in bundle.

Please help.

Comment: are you updating your bundle data. From this it seems you are passing same data again to it

Comment: yes I am sending updated bundle

Comment: try removing your fragments also and add them again